# How can I split an html5 table of one column into two?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have an array with some nested arrays and those nested arrays consists of strings and objects. I want to display the name of the superheroes` based on the values they have in the object and therefore color them accordingly.

I was successful in rendering the table where there is one row (`tr`) for each item in the array and the row consists of only one column (`td`). But I am unable to render the table where there will be one row (`tr`) for each two items. That is, there will be two columns (`td`) each row.

This is what I have right now:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Here's the code:

```js
const tdEls         = [];
const arr         = [
  [
    'superman', {'flight': 'yes'}
  ],
  [
    'batman', {'flight': 'no'}
  ],
  [
    'green arrow', {'superstrength': 'no'}
  ],
  [
    'penguin', {'flight': 'yes'}
  ],
  [
    'shazam', {'flight': 'no'}
  ],
  [
    'wonderwoman', {'flight': 'yes'}
  ],
  [
    'cyborg', {'flight': 'no'}
  ],
  [
    'flash', {'superstrength': 'no'}
  ],
  [
    'martian', {'superstrength': 'no'}
  ],
  [
    'joker', {'flight': 'no'}
  ],
  [
    'robin', {'differentWorld': 'no'}
  ]
];


for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
      if( arr[i][1].flight && arr[i][1].flight === 'yes' ) {
          tdEls.push(`
              <tr>
                  <td style="color:red;">${arr[i][0]}</td>
              </tr>
          `);
      }

      if( arr[i][1].flight && arr[i][1].flight === 'no' ) {
          tdEls.push(`
              <tr>
                  <td style="color:green;">${arr[i][0]}</td>
              </tr>
          `);
      }

      if( arr[i][1].superstrength && arr[i][1].superstrength === 'no') {
          tdEls.push(`
              <tr>
                  <td style="color:orange;">${arr[i][0]}</td>
              </tr>
          `);
      }

      if( arr[i][1].differentWorld && arr[i][1].differentWorld === 'no' ) {
          tdEls.push(`
              <tr>
                  <td style="color:blue;">${arr[i][0]}</td>
              </tr>
          `);
      }
}

document.querySelector('table').innerHTML = tdEls.join('');
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: A table with more than one column can be reflected by an array of arrays. Try creating that from the original array, where each element of the main array represents a table row, and its elements the cells. Once you have that, turning it into HTML is easy. (needless to say, this is a basic problem with lots of existing solutions) ((also, you need to get away from looking at this as "splitting an HTML table", and "composing a string of HTML". this is about (re)structuring data, and only that))

Comment: Just remove the `<tr>` and `</tr>` from what you're pushing to the array. Push them into the array every two iterations. Most people use the modulus operator (`%`) to do that. Or you could restructure your data as @ChrisG recommends. Restructuring your data would allow you to write the code that generates the HTML once and have it react to the structure of the data so if you want three columns tomorrow, you just restructure the data and not your code.

Comment: Hey @ChrisG, isn't that what I did in my code? The snippet I've provided shows that I'm looping through the main array and then based on data I'm creating TRs and the corresponding TDs. If you could explain what you meant with a little bit of code, that'd be great.

Comment: @HereticMonkey But even if I restructure the data, I'll face the same problem right as I have to loop through the data and then create trs and tds based on conditionals?

Comment: You'll face a similar problem, but not the same. No matter what, you're going to have to separate the creation of the table rows from the creation of the table cells. Personally, I'd do it once; Create a function that takes an array of arrays. For each element in the inner array, create a table row. Within that, for each element in the sub-array, create a table cell. Basically two nested loops. There are examples all over Stack Overflow with code aplenty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take a look into those.

Comment: No, not at all. You are just turning a list of elements into a list of <tr>s. I'm referring to an *array of arrays*, i.e. a two-dimensional array. Technically you already have an array of arrays, but that's only because you used an array to store a single superhero for some reason.

Comment: This doesn’t appear to be tabular data, so why not use a (probably) more appropriate `<ul>` or `<ol>`, along with CSS grid?

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/267j5mco/ (Note that there's way easier ways to arrange the names in the desired way; only an actual table/tr/td requires all this. Flexbox for example doesn't require any of this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can chunk in two cells and use the object keys plus values as classnames

PS: Penguin could not fly. He used a flight umbrella.

```js
const arr = [ [ 'superman', {'flight': 'yes'} ], [ 'batman', {'flight': 'no'} ], [ 'green arrow', {'superstrength': 'no'} ], [ 'penguin', {'flight': 'yes'} ], [ 'shazam', {'flight': 'no'} ], [ 'wonderwoman', {'flight': 'yes'} ], [ 'cyborg', {'flight': 'no'} ], [ 'flash', {'superstrength': 'no'} ], [ 'martian', {'superstrength': 'no'} ], [ 'joker', {'flight': 'no'} ], [ 'robin', {'differentWorld': 'no'} ] ]; 

const chunk =  (arr, len) => {
  let chunks = [], i = 0, n = arr.length;
  while (i < n)  chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  return chunks;
};

const tdEls = arr.map(hero => `<td class="${Object.keys(hero[1])}${Object.values(hero[1])}">${hero[0]}</td>`)
document.querySelector('table tbody').innerHTML = chunk(tdEls,2).map(cnk => `<tr>${cnk.join("")}</tr>`).join("")
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flightyes {
  color: red
}

.flightno {
  color: green
}

.superstrengthno {
  color: orange
}

.differentWorldno {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<table><tbody></tbody></table>
```